# How to stop Google image search settings from resetting every search?

Tags: images, google-search

Every time I search with some filter (under the regular tools option or advanced search), the filters disappear once I search another term. Is there a way to make the settings stick somehow?

Answer (score 2):

I don't know of a dedicated option to make the settings stick, but a workaround is to change the URL instead of the search field.

Suppose you're searching for [images of red flowers](https://www.google.com/search?as_st=y&tbm=isch&hl=en&as_q=flower&as_epq=&as_oq=&as_eq=&cr=&as_sitesearch=&safe=images&tbs=ic:specific,isc:red):

[image]

The search term, 'flower', appears both in the search field *and* in the address bar. If you change it in the address bar to e.g. 'shoes', Google will remember the settings because they're in the other parameters in the URL:

[image]